# ¿ Cambiar un valor de un elemento dentro de un componente de bootstrap con javascript?

Tags: javascript, html5, css3

Tengo un componente de Bootstrap en este caso una barra de progreso y quiero cambiar un valor de esta barra de progreso mediante JavaScript.

```
<div id="barra1">
   <h3 class="progress-title">Paso 1</h3>
   <div class="progress blue">
     <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped active" role="progressbar" style="width:0%;">
       <div class="progress-value">0%</div>
     </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

He probado con lo siguiente pero no funciona:

```
document.getElementById("barra1.progress-value").innerHTML = "5%";
```

En cambio si coloco directamente en el elemento que esta dentro del componente si que funciona pero preferiría hacer referencia al componente 'barra1' desde el contenedor div de alguna manera para que el código se entendiera mejor, ya que puedo tener muchos componentes mas.

```
<div id="idValue" class="progress-value">0%</div>

document.getElementById("idValue").innerHTML = "5%";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que la función `getElementById` solamente trabaja con el atributo `id`, no clases, si necesitas un selector más avanzado puedes usar [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)

```js
document
  .getElementById('boton')
  .addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    var element = document.querySelectorAll('#barra1 .progress-value')[0];
    element.innerText = '5%';
  });
```

```html
<div id="barra1">
   <h3 class="progress-title">Paso 1</h3>
   <div class="progress blue">
     <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped active" role="progressbar" style="width:0%;">
       <div class="progress-value">0%</div>
     </div>
   </div>
</div>
<button id="boton">Cambiar</button>
```

Comment: Buena solución ! Perfecto gracias !